# Cassandra Live Migration from onpremises to the Compute Engine / VM

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

We are having Cassandra 3.10 in the onprem. We need to perform a live migration, it will be a cluster can you share the documentation of how it needs to be done. Is it more like adding the VM servers as part of the existing onprem cluster ? And then finally do the cutover ? Does an Different Cassandra version be used in Onprem or should we need to go with the same version have any one faced issue while trying replication with two different major / minor version please share your experiences.

Thanks in advance.

Steps for Live migrations, issues faced while performing and cross version replication is possible ?

Comment: I would add a 2nd data center in the cloud environment. Use the same version of cassandra - that's a requirement. Replicate the 1st data center to the 2nd data center. When you're sure that the data is being replicated, then switch your data ingestion path to the new data center. Finally when all is running, decomission the onprem data center. Try it on a test data center to get the steps down